# Excel VBA change semicolon to colon automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I've made an Excel workbook, where people can type their work times. Is it possible to map the semicolon to colon? It should put a colon if the user tries to input a semicolon.

I'm alredy using `Application.OnKey "^x", ""` to disable the cutting function, when the workbook is active. I tried something like `Application.OnKey ";", ":"` but it isn't working.

Comment: You could use the worksheet change event (if all the user input is done on a singe sheet) to scrape the user input and replace all ";" with ":"

Comment: Did you consider using data validation to restrict to cells in question to only allow valid time values?: https://wmfexcel.com/2014/08/10/data-validation-time/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Replace()` method of `Range` object with `xlPart` value for its `lookAt` parameter:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Replace what:=";", replacement:=":", lookat:=xlPart
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Worksheet Change event to capture user input and replace the semi-colons with colons, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Target
        Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, ";", ":")
    Next cell

End Sub
```

This will only work if you are listening for user input in a single sheet. If you want to listen to all sheets, you would just do something similar in the Workbook change event.

Comment: Thank you! Since I have multiple sheets, one for each month, your advice about the workbook-change helped.